# ML Predicted Model for 2 values

Tags: machine-learning, python, data-science-model, unsupervised-learning

I have a data set with 96 rows. It contains date, source, spend and number of customers.
I have 4 different sources that generate customers and you can see in the dataset how much I spend and how many customers I have received by month for the last two years.
I have a budget for 2023 for each source by month and I would like to know how many customers will I get for 2023.

EXAMPLE DATA SET
[Click to see data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WJAt8fvlF26QlbNxqPwaMtzLeI1qg927i-zfEIJZSZk/edit#gid=0)

I have tried a few models such as multilinear regression but it didn't perform great. Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice example of (rather small) time series analysis. And given how small the dataset is, you will have a hard time making it good, in the first place.

I would default to AR(I)MA analysis, given you have only two years of data that would not allow for detection of seasonality. Make a different, but as good as possible ARIMA model for every source and make the prediction the sum of the sources (expected prediction of the sum is the same as the sum of the predictions).

I have not seen a clearer example of data series analysis, just pick the method of modelling properly (forget about trees on such a small dataset, especially since you are predicting a continuous target)